# How to install codec g729 on asterisk server

Tags: asterisk, codec

I tried more but i am unable to install codec g729 on asterisk server.

the `uname -i` return x86_64

the model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1271 v3 @ 3.60GHz

Asterisk version 13.1

Comment: does this help you? http://asterisk.hosting.lv/

Comment: yes i tried this but i am unable to do this

Answer (score 4):

Use following steps to install g729 codec:

```
[root@localhost ~]#cd /usr/src  
[root@localhost src]#wget http://asterisk.hosting.lv/bin/codec_g729-ast18-gcc4-glibc-pentium4.so  
[root@localhost src]#cp codec_g729-ast18-gcc4-glibc-pentium4.so /usr/lib/asterisk/modules/codec_g729.so  
[root@localhost src]#chmod  +x /usr/lib/asterisk/modules/codec_g729.so  
[root@localhost src]#asterisk -rx "module load codec_g729.so"  
[root@localhost src]#service asterisk restart
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but .my asterisk server is 13.1 and the model name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1271 v3 @ 3.60GHz  so this will not work

Comment: Go through this link http://downloads.digium.com/pub/telephony/codec_g729/README You fill find complete details  here only, Also If you are using asterisk 13 then download the same package from here only http://downloads.digium.com/pub/telephony/codec_g729/asterisk-13.0/x86-64/